# Logic Apps: Run query and visualize results Html Table displayed in Email

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics

I would like to display the results of my query in a html table via email.

My attempt:

[image]

The above is attaching the .html to the email but i would like to display it in the email.

Comment: Are you not getting the email body by using `Attachment Content` in it?

Comment: if you replicate this with any query. it will provide a giant string / hash. but im expecting a table.

Comment: Yes it is a string but when you will trigger the logic app, you should receive email body in html format just by using attachment content

Comment: I am getting result like [this](https://i.imgur.com/RZXIsqg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that does not require you to attach the .html file to the email.

Instead i've used run query and list results + create html table. Then wrapped the table in html to then be used inside an email.

[image]